# Where is this default spacing coming from?

Tags: html, css

I have this webpage divided into multiple sections, and want to know where the default spacing below the "Price" section is coming from. Could someone help me I've tried multiple solutions to get rid of it but it will not.

Here's the codepen: https://codepen.io/Lightisicus/pen/gOxPgGy

```
                <section class="price">
                    <h2>Price</h2>
                </section>
                <section class="price-flex content-dimensions">
                    <span class="main-text-font-size">$1699</span>
                    <span class="main-text-font-size">$1949</span>
                    <span class="placeholder">placeholder</span>
                </section>
```

Comment: You should learn to use the [browser's tools](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/wordpress/browsers-inspect-element-tool) to see that .

Comment: Yep, that is what I did.  I learned `.display` is adding a bottom top and bottom padding of `3.2rem`.

Answer (score 0):

It comes from this CSS rule:

```
.price-flex {
    max-width: 75%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 3.2rem;
}
```

`position: relative` and `bottom: 3.2rem;` cause an offset of that element, moving it "into" the element above it, but still leaving the space which is reserved for that element, which is the space you see.

Adding `margin-bottom: -3.2rem;` will make that space disappear by adding a negative margin.

Comment: hmm, that actually did not work and i'm not sure why, basically in this section I want the padding to be the same on the top and bottom, but the price values are actually wrapped in a flex-container themselves so that's creating that extra space at the bottom, so the bottom padding ends up being more than the top. I just want the price caption and the values to align in one straight line and have the padding be equal on the top and bottom.